Are there standards that determine the display of results for built-in tests in avionics?
I have seen GO/NGO on some pages to show the pilot the result of a built-in test. However, in some documents I have also seen TEST OK/TEST FAIL, or perhaps just PASS/FAIL. Is there some ARINC or SAE standard that gives guidance on this?
